Excel previous result formulas to Power BI
    K            L                  M                  N
17  Date      Daily Start Goal  Daily Billed hrs    Daily End Outcome
18  7/1/2024            
19  7/2/2024    5.45                 3.90              -1.55
20  7/3/2024    7.01                 5.30              -1.71
21  7/4/2024    7.16                 1.20              -5.96
22  7/5/2024    11.42                7.40              -4.02
23  7/8/2024    9.47                 8.60              -0.87
24  7/9/2024    6.33                 3.20              -3.13
25  7/10/2024   8.58                 4.80              -3.78

I need to get this table in Power BI where:

Date= date registries in a table called timeslips

Daily Billed hrs= data of daily registry of worked hours in a table called timeslips

Daily Start Goal = IFS(N18<0, $I$6-N18, N18>0, $I$6-N18,ISBLANK(N18), $I$6)
Where:
N18= Previous day End value,
$I$6=Avg/Day calculation.

Daily End Outcome  =IFS(L19>M19,M19-L19,L19<M19,M19-L19)
Where:
L19= Goal value,
M19=hrs value


I need to create Daily Start Goal and Daily End Outcome columns in Power BI avoiding the circular dependency, having an initial table with Date and Daily Billed hrs columns and an Avg/Day measure.
I tried creating Daily Start Goal and Daily End Outcome measures, but I'm getting a circular dependency error:
Goal =  VAR PreviousEnd = CALCULATE ([End],PREVIOUSDAY ( timeslips[timeslip_date] )) 
        VAR AvgPerDay = [AVG/Day]  -- Replace with your actual measure for Avg/Day 
RETURN 
        IF(ISBLANK(PreviousEnd), AvgPerDay, AvgPerDay - PreviousEnd)

End =
VAR CurrentGoal = [Goal]
VAR CurrentHours = SUM(Timeslips[Daily Billed hrs])
RETURN
IF(
CurrentGoal > CurrentHours,
CurrentGoal - CurrentHours,
CurrentHours - CurrentGoal
)


is this the raw table or table visual? what's the data for I6?

Hi, this is the visual the raw data is basically the K and the M column and the I6 is the result of a measure called Avg/Day the result is fix for each month so for this particular example is 5.45. Thank you

it's better to provide the raw data and the expected output based on the data you provided. We need to understand the whole story.
